# cpp- Attempt to take address of value not located in memory

Tags: c++

I have a class with the following private member:

```
class Student
{
     public:
        Student(std::string name_ , int const id_);
        virtual ~Student();
        void addGrade(int const grade2add);//grade above 100

    private:
        std::string name;  //max 20 chars
        int const id; //5 digits, only digits
        std::vector<int> grades;
        static int  maxGrade;
        static int freq_grades[100];

};
```

I have to check that the lentgh of the id is equal to 5 and contains only digit.
I checked it in the constructor in the following way:

```
Student::Student(std::string name_, int const id_): name(name_), id(id_)
{
    string idStr=to_string(id);
    if (name.size()>=20)
    {
        throw(121);
        //cout<<"Name should be less than 20 chars"<<endl;
    }
    if (idStr.size()!=5)
    {
        throw(122);
         //cout<<"Id should be 5 nums"<<endl;
    }
    if (!all_of(idStr.begin(), idStr.end(),  ::isdigit))
    {
        throw(123);
    }
}
```

The program exit because the condition of the size (thogh the input is 12345, so it suppose to be legal). When I debug and watch isStr.size() I got "Attempt to take address of value not located in memory."

Comment: I think you meant `int const id`

Comment: @HappyCoder They meant _other stuff_ anyways. That sampe is bogus and useless to reproduce a [MCVE]

Comment: @ Ed Heal- it does compile

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ- it is certainly bogus and useles!!! I am new to cpp, and encounter some issues. If you don't know the answer don't comment.

Comment: A integer with a minimum of 5 digits is a number larger or equal to 10000. wouldn't testing for id >= 10000 make more sense?

Comment: @ user1320881- i have to verify that the id contains only digits (use try and catch).

Comment: but it is of type int, it can be nothing else but a integer.

Comment: Just a note, if id =1 than it isn't 5 characters, best thing to do would be probably be `if (id < 10000 || id > 100000)` then do your throw.

Also it's very odd to be throwing integers... Most things I've read about C++ exceptions says you can do it, but you shouldn't

Comment: @ Ed Heal- there was a mistake in the decleration of the id. In the origin code it is written correctly (const)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This whole approach is kind of barmy.

An integer converted to a string can never contain anything other than numeric digits (or `-`). It's a number. Plus you can check the range numerically (and handle the `-` as part of that). So your conversion is pointless and leading your debugging to be harder than necessary.

Why not just the following simple function?

```
Student::Student(const std::string& name_, int const id_)
  : name(name_)
  , id(id_)
{
    if (name.empty() || name.size() >= 20)
        throw std::runtime_error("Name must have 1-20 chars");

    // Require that the ID has exactly five decimal digits (also implies positive)
    if (id < 10000 || id > 99999)
        throw std::runtime_error("ID must have five decimal digits");
}
```

Now when your code fails (which nobody can reproduce), simply output the value of `id` to console, or set a watch on `id`, and put breakpoints in the relevant conditional block.

Comment: It appears that the program exit because some command in the main function. Though I still don't understand why I can't see the value of " idStr.size() " while debug

Comment: @sara8: Probably small-string optimisation vs debugger incompatibility. These are the pitfalls of trying to use a runtime debugger's "watch" facility to execute arbitrary code expressions on code that's more complex than it needs to be. At these times, a simple `std::cerr << idStr.size() << '\n'` is a much easier way to debug.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet- 10x. By the way I veify if the id contains only digits because the user doesn't neceserly know that the id is "int" , and I want to inform the user about the error, and not just terminate the program.

Comment: @sara8: But that condition can literally never fail. The user would never be informed if the ID contained something other than digits, because it's impossible for the ID to contain anything other than digits (or `-`). So it's pointless. Doesn't matter whether the user knows the ID is an `int` or not: you do.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet- so should I define the id as a string?

Comment: @sara8 `int const id` means id is a integer and can ONLY contain a number. If the user enters anything else then a number this error is handled by the function performing the input as it cannot assign a non-number to int.

Comment: @sara8: What? No... Is there some specific problem you have with the code I've shown you? I think that this solution is very simple.

Comment: @ BarryTheHatchet- No. Everything is clear. I just wonder if I have to change the id to string so I can inform the user in case of error.

Comment: @sara8 handle/inform the user where it should be handled, at the point the number is aquired.

Answer (score 0):

If the code `int cost id;` compiles something weird is going on, perhaps `cost` is defined as a macro? Anyway I am assuming here you really meant `int const id;`.

So I compiled and ran the following file, using Visual C++ 2015, and it worked with the input "John" and "12345" so you should not be getting an error.

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
public:
    Student(std::string name_, int const id_);
private:
    std::string name;
    int const id;
};

Student::Student(std::string name_, int const id_) : name(name_), id(id_)
{
    string idStr = to_string(id);
    if (name.size() >= 20)
    {
        throw(121);
        cout<<"Name should be less than 20 chars"<<endl;
    }
    if (idStr.size() != 5)
    {
        throw(122);
        cout<<"Id should be 5 nums"<<endl;
    }
    if (!all_of(idStr.begin(), idStr.end(), ::isdigit))
    {
        throw(123);
    }
}

int main()
{
    string n = "";
    cin >> n;
    int i = 0;
    cin >> i;
    Student s {n, i};
    cin.ignore(2);
}
```

What compiler/OS are you using? does other C++ code work? Perhaps your compiler is broken, or there is something wrong with other parts of your code that you have not shown. More information would be verry useful!

Comment: -I edit and add the header file.

Comment: @sara8 It still works.. (though I did have to implement the destructor with `{}` I am assuming you have actually implemented it somewhere...)